# Dynamically change font of a table with Angular and CSS

Tags: css, angular

I am working on an Angular project. I have this table, which I build but I don't know in advance how big the font should be. Because of that i created this function (this is the code i have inside of it):

```
$('.td').css({
    'font-size': Number(this.f) + 'px'
});

//Mobile
  $('.mobileTdLong').css({
      'width': Number(this.f) + 150 + 'px'
  });

  $('.mobileTdShort').css({
    'width': Number(this.f) + 40 + 'px'
  });

//Desktop
  $('.tableDesktopShort').css({
    'width': Number(this.f) + 100 + 'px'
  });
```

NOTE: f is a variable from user input.

The code I have written isn't the best one for my problem because it doesn't permenantly change my table font.. It just flickers (from `20px` which is set by default in .css file, to this.f value). The reason I need this is because every 10 seconds the table values are refreshed.

I hope I provided enough information. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should get rid of everything that is jquery related. It does not belong in an Angular solution
And then you should handle the styling with CSS media queries

Comment: Thanks i looked into it. However i didn't find how this should be set up. Could you give an example?

Comment: ok i think i found that this does the trick : [style.font-size.px]="f"

Comment: seriously, you should spend some time on understanding Angular better, and get rid of all jquery. Also take it out of your package.json.
I can recommend Angular course on udemy, by Maximllian.

Comment: i agree, thats why i asked this question :) and i am already following Maximilian on Udemy thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS 1.7 or Angular 6.0?
instead of a jquery lite selector, you can try inline styles :

```
<table [ngStyle]="getStylesTableOnMobileView()">
 ...
</table>
```

you can also do same with ngClass.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use jQuery in Angular. If you need to dinamically change classes of html elements I recommend you to use `[(ngClass)]` or media queries.